# Running a test with tox based on a keyword

Tags: pytest, tox

I am using pytest with tox. I can run some of my tests with a keyword like this:

`pytest -k <keyword> path/to/tests`

Now it would be really convenient to be able to do this also with tox, as the environments there are clean and different python versions can be tested. However the nearest thing I have found is:

`tox -- path/to/tests/test_very_specific_name.py:TestClass.test_func`

This is not easy to type, so I rather just run tox without arguments and wait 2 minutes for everything to finish.

Is there a way to run single tests based on keywords with tox? I tried:

`tox -- -k <keyword>`

This results in a huge list of import errors. It doesn't seem to be able to find any of my local includes. Is this supposed to work?

Comment: `tox` doesn't interpret arguments after `--` — it just passes the as `{posargs}`. You should show us your `tox.ini` so we can see how do you use `{posargs}`.

Comment: Ah thanks, that was the problem. I was using {posargs} wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to the comment by phd.

Everything on the command line after -- can be used in tox.ini as {posargs}. I was using that wrong. My tox.ini now has a line like this:

`commands = py.test {posargs} <test_folder>`

Now it works perfectly with:

`tox -- -k <keyword>`